# "a sense of" vs "a feeling of"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, word-difference

1. a feeling of
2. a sense of

I am confused about these two phrases. I have learned the usages of them for instance:

> 1. a feeling of satisfaction/pride
>      &
> 2. a sense of humor/direction

but I still can't figure out the difference between the two phrases.

Could you show me some more examples to help me distinguish? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to ELL. The distinction between _sense_ and _feeling_ is subtle and nice, but if you read _several_ dictionaries carefully, you will understand it. What dictionaries did you consult? Please tell us by adding your thoughts to the question by using the [edit] link. Also please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages to learn more about how to write a useful question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sense** when in the context of an ideal or a virtue or an ability (such as "humor" or "justice" or "irony" or "direction" or "responsibility") is synonymous with "intelligent understanding of and an appreciation for" something.

**feeling** when in the context of mental states (such as "pride" or "embarrassment" or "delight" or  "shame" or "envy" or "confusion") refers to an emotional state.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be blurring the distinction between *sense* and *sensation*. It is true that *sense* can mean *feeling*, as in

> A perception or feeling produced by a stimulus; sensation: *a sense of fatigue and hunger*

but it can also mean

> A capacity to appreciate or understand: *a keen sense of humor*

So you could use *sense* or *feeling* to fill in the following blank:

> I had a _________ of having been there before.

But while you might grammatically say

> He had a good feeling of humor.

when you mean to say the person had a good *sense* of humor, it would be awkward and confusing (and would sound foreign to the native speaker's ear) because it would not mean what you intended.

Still, you could easily change the preposition and say:

> He had a good feeling *for* humor.

This version, though related, also has a different meaning.

<sup><sub>[Definitions from TFD Online](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sense)</sub></sup>