# physical: "sense" vs. "feeling"

Tags: word-usage

[Meaning of sense on Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sense)

> a general feeling or understanding

Meaning of feeling on Cambridge Dictionary

> the fact of feeling something physical

[I am teaching my son football juggling.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/249498/115654)

> Raise your foot. Hold the ball ... just let the ball touch your foot and bounce up by itself the same way it bounces on the ground. practice this repeatedly and you will get the 
>   **sense/feeling** of how a ball bounce.

In this particular situation, should I use "sense" or "feeling"?

[As per an ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/105634/115654), it seems both "sense" and "feeling" are suitable here, is my understanding right?

Comment: I would agree that both words are valid.

Comment: @Cardinal Yes, you're right. Btw, what does "S.N" refer to?

Comment: I meant side note (^_^)/